# Regular Expression Valid and Invalid togather

Tags: c++, regex

I the below items i want to only detect the valid items with regular expression.
Space in word means invalid, # sign means invalid, Starting word with number is invalid.

```
Invalid : M_123 ASD
Invalid : M_123#ASD
Invalid : 1_M# ADD
Valid : M_125ASD
Valid : M_125$ASD
```

I am trying as below :

```
[A-Za-z0-9_$]
```

Not working properly. I need to set both valid and invalid sets for a word.

Can i do a match with regular expression?

Comment: Schrodinger's regex.

Comment: is the starting always an alphabet??

Comment: Try [`^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_$]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/2cc86W/3). Or if there can be a `$` or `_` at the start, try [`^[A-Za-z_$][A-Za-z0-9_$]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/2cc86W/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked for me. Please post as an answer so that i can mark it solved.

Comment: Which one? Both?

Comment: First one 
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_$]*$.

Comment: Ok, posted with explanation and hints on usage (just in case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `[A-Za-z0-9_$]` presents a character class that matches a single character that is either an ASCII letter or digit, or `_` or `$` symbols. If you use it with `std::regex_match`, it would only match a *whole string* that consists of just one char like that since the pattern is anchored by default when used with that method. If you use it with an `std::regex_search`, a string like `([_])` would pass, since the regex is not *anchored* and can find *partial* matches.

To match 0 or more chars, you need to add `*` quantifier after your class. To match one or more chars, you need to add `+` quantifier after your character class. However, you have an additional restriction: a digit cannot appear at the start.

It seems you may use

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_$]*$
```

See the [regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2cc86W/3).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter (exactly one occurrence)
- `[A-Za-z0-9_$]*` - 0+ ASCII letters, digits, `_` or `$`
- `$` - end of string anchor.

Note that with `regex_match`, you may omit `^` and `$` anchors.

Answer (score 0):

So the requirements are

- cannot start with number( i am assuming it as start with alphabet)
- cannot contain space or #
- all other characters are valid

you can try this regex `^[a-zA-Z]((?![\# ]).)+?$`

`^[a-zA-Z]` checks for alphabet at start of the line
`((?![\# ]).)+?$` checks if there are no `#` or `space` in the remaining part of the line.

Online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vqxBRk/1)

**EDIT**

As per Wiktor's comment the regex can be simplified to `^[a-zA-Z][^# ]+$`.

Comment: Your regex is almost the same as `^[a-zA-Z][^# ]+$`, it is a much more readable version.

Comment: ah thx for the improvement Wiktor.. i always go for the lookaheads without even noticing it myself..